# Access subclass data member from superclass array initialized using subclass objects

Tags: c++, inheritance, object-slicing

A minimal reproducible example:

```cpp
#include<iostream>

class Super
{
    private:
    int data1;
    
    public:
    virtual int getData1(){return data1;}
};

class Sub1:public Super
{
    private:
    static const int data1 = 1;
} sub1;

class Sub2:public Super
{
    private:
    static const int data1 = 3;
} sub2;

int main()
{
    Super obj[]={sub1, sub2};
    std::cout<<obj[0].getData1()<<'\n';
    std::cout<<obj[1].getData1()<<'\n';
    return 0;
}
```

> What I need:
> 1
> 3

> What I got:
> 0
> 0

How can I achieve this?

I found the following during my search -
[Are static variables in a base class shared by all derived classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390913/are-static-variables-in-a-base-class-shared-by-all-derived-classes)
[Accessing subclass members from a superclass pointer C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559854/accessing-subclass-members-from-a-superclass-pointer-c)
[C++ override a member variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37976088/c-override-a-member-variable)

[Accessing subclass members from a superclass pointer C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559854/accessing-subclass-members-from-a-superclass-pointer-c) looks similar but it doesn't solve my query.

**EDIT:**
I was informed that this happens due to [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).

Comment: See also: [What is slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing). Even if you override `getData1` in `Sub1` and `Sub2`, that won't do you any good if you have an array of `Super` objects.

Comment: @NathanPierson Noted. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

You may reference this similar question: [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)

The ways to avoid this is to use pointers or references, we may consider a `vector` of `unique_ptr` or `boost::ptr_vector` or `vector` of `reference_wrapper`, but to use reference we need to be careful since we may encounter dangling reference then get a crash(The referenced object may be destroyed).

```cpp
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_vector.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Super {
 private:
  int data1;

 public:
  virtual int getData1() { return data1; }
};

class Sub1 : public Super {
 private:
  static const int data1 = 1;

 public:
  int getData1() { return data1; }
} sub1;

class Sub2 : public Super {
 private:
  static const int data1 = 3;

 public:
  int getData1() { return data1; }
} sub2;

void choice1() {
  std::unique_ptr<Super> obj[] = {std::make_unique<Sub1>(),
                                  std::make_unique<Sub2>()};
  std::cout << obj[0]->getData1() << '\n';
  std::cout << obj[1]->getData1() << '\n';
}
void choice2() {
  boost::ptr_vector<Super> vec;
  vec.push_back(new Sub1);
  vec.push_back(new Sub2);
  std::cout << vec[0].getData1() << '\n';
  std::cout << vec[1].getData1() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Does not compile.
`fatal error: boost/ptr_container/ptr_vector.hpp: No such file or directory`
   


Executes well without `#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_vector.hpp>` and `choice2()`

Comment: You need to install `boost` library. If your are using ubuntu/debian, you can simply type `sudo apt install libboost-dev`; For other Linux or Windows platform, just google it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, your choice1() method doesn't work if the functions are not overridden. Is there a way to avoid that?